# loop thru JSON object and dynamically output to textbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the below JSON object returned to me and want to update the val() of two textboxes (txtAssigned01 and txtAssigned02) that already exist on the page. I know I should do this with a loop, but not sure how to dynamically select the textboxes in jQuery. Any help would be appreciated!

JSON Object:
[image]

Code so far:

```
function getAssignedPerson(projectID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "view-requests.aspx/getAssignedPerson",   // Current Page, Method
            data: JSON.stringify({
                projectID: projectID
            }), // parameter map as JSON
            type: "POST", // data has to be POSTed
            contentType: "application/json", // posting JSON content    
            dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)
            timeout: 10000,    // AJAX timeout
            success: function (result) {

                $.each(result, function (i, v) {
                    $('#txtAssigned0'+ v).val(result.d[i]); <--- here's my problem
                });

            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you try .attr("name","somename") ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44mUL/).

You have the following HTML on the page:

```
<input id='txtAssigned01'/>
<input id='txtAssigned02'/>
```

Your data looks like it's coming back as follows:

```
var result = {d:['test1', 'test2']};
```

So you need to loop the array d that is in the result object:

```
$.each(result.d, function (i, v) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(v);
    var x = i + 1;
    $('#txtAssigned0'+ x).val(v); //<--- here's my problem
});
```

You also need to increment the index which is zero based or change your naming convention to be zero based such that you would have:

```
<input id='txtAssigned00'/>
<input id='txtAssigned01'/>
```

and

```
$.each(result.d, function (i, v) {
    $('#txtAssigned0'+ i).val(v); 
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44mUL/1/).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add a new text box and name it you can use the following:

```
$('<input>').attr({type: 'text').val("YOUR_VALUE").appendTo('#ID_OF_SOME PARENT_DOM_OBJ')
```

You can also add more stuff such as on_click handlers by saying for exampl

```
$('<input>').attr({type: 'text').val("YOUR_VALUE").appendTo('#ID_OF_SOME PARENT_DOM_OBJ').click(function(){alert('hello');});
```

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry if I didn't explain very well. The textboxes (txtAssignedPerson01 and txAssignedPerson02) are already on the page, I just want to update their val() with a loop from the JSON object. Does that make sense?

Comment: The only problem with your original snippet is that when you use `$.each` the indices start from 0, so you might as well want to change either the ids of your textboxes to `txtAssigned00` and `txtAssigned01` or change `+ i` to `+ (i+1)`. Besides that your code is doing what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $.each(result, function (i, v) {
           $("#main").append("<input type='text' value='"+v+"' id='txtAssigned_"+i+"' ");
        });
```

where #main will be some div with id 'main' in which text field will be displayed